# Input data into excel and update formulas on Mac

Tags: r, excel

I have a list of data text files and I'm trying to put that data into an excel file and then update the formulas based on the data. The excel file has several sheets with a hundred columns that do successive calculations. The code looks like:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- loadWorkbook(excel_file)
writeData(wb, sheet = 'data', x = blank, startCol = 2, startRow = 23)
saveWorkbook(wb,'Desktop/excel_file.xlsx',overwrite = TRUE)
```

Inputting the data into the excel which works fine but the formulas are not updating when I use `read_excel`. I have to manually open the document and save it. There are hundreds of data files so that would be a huge hassle to have to do that.

It seems other people have had the same issue. Is there really no way to view the data with the updated formulas programmatically? Is installing an older java and using `xlsx` the only way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Do NOT capitalize `library` or any other R function what is not documented as having a first letter as capital, which is most R functions.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround would be to open, then close, the file in Excel at the time of saving using `system2()`. e.g., with a helper function like this:

```
saveUpdateWorkbook <- function(wb, file, ...) {
  out <- saveWorkbook(wb = wb, file = file, ...)
  system2("open", file)
  # Sys.sleep(5) # would have to test if you need this and for how long
  system2("killall", "Microsoft Excel")
  out
}
```

Variants include a function that takes multiple workbooks and paths and opens them all before killing the Excel process; or a function that opens in Excel immediately before loading in R (rather than opening immediately after saving from R as here).

Note I’m not a Mac user and haven’t tested this, so may well need tweaking.

Comment: I don't have a full version of MS Excel, but this works with the crippled version, at least to the extent of opening and closing an existing file. I doubt that the working directory would get prepended to the file name, however, so the value given to `file` would need to be a fully qualified "path/to/filename.xlsx"